# How to resume OneDrive Uploads?

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, onedrive, upload

On my machine, I have approximately 50GB in my OneDrive directory (and a 1TB capacity on OneDrive), and I find that after rebooting, typically 2 GB or so of this data gets uploaded to OneDrive then then the upload mysteriously stops, typically with a few files in intermediate states of upload. It seems the only way to resume uploads is to reboot the machine, then wait for the synchronization process to resume for a few more GB of data.

I realize that MS operating systems require reboots all the time, but this is a little over the top.  Does anyone know of a less disruptive and annoying way to resume OneDrive uploads... or to prevent them from stopping in the first place?

Comment: I assume all updates are installed?

Comment: I haven't been able to install the optional update KB3000850 without an update failure... and now I see it has a fix for this problem.

Comment: You need to determine the reason your unable to install that update.

Comment: I have odd issues with OneDrive not completing uploads even though the file is not in use and it not a big file. I just see the refresh icon next to file. Seems like a bug they are not addressing yet. Plenty of those in the Microsoft world.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your OS is windows 8 or similar, you can right click on the folder and do a sync. 
if on a mac, i quit one drive (from the menu bar icon) and start for restarting the sync. 
--Gopa

Comment: The problem was that Sync was active but not transferring files.